# Object instantiation when dependency is missing (Java)

Tags: java, object, instantiation, classloader

Guys, can anyone explain the following scenario:

1) Web application has `module1.jar` in its `lib` directory. There is a class `A` in that module:

```
package module1;
import module2.B;
public interface IA {   
    void methodOk() {}

    void methodWithB(B param) {}
}

package module1;
import module2.B;
public class A implements IA {
    public A() {}

    //...
void methodWithB(B param) {
    //do job on B
}
}
```

2) `module2.jar` is absent - it is not in the classpath.

3) Application **is able** to create objects of class `A` though it's missing the dependency. In application a method A.methodOk() is called.

Would be cool if you could give a reference to any spec on this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does A *use* B anywhere?

Comment: @Joseph: I've edited #4 point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the code is already compiled, it will not throw an error until you directly use class `B`. From the looks of your code, you don't actually use an instance of `B` for anything.

Comment: @Jeremy: Can you elaborate on this? I mean it is a surprise for me that object can be constructed (I'm lacking the knowlegde on JVM internals)...

Comment: Tell us where in your code that an instance of `B` is constructed? Keep in mind, only the code that is **executed** at runtime matters. If an instance of `B` is never constructed, then the JVM doesn't need to blow up.

Comment: @Jeremy: can't say you at the moment where B is constructed (left comp at work :), may be nowhere... You state that class may be constructed while not having ALL of its dependencies known to classloader. What makes this possible? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: This is possible because the JVM doesn't perform the same static analysis as the compiler. If the JVM (via a ClassLoader) doesn't need to actually load a class, then whether or not it exists is irrelevant. The JVM is under the assumption the compiler has done its job and that classes will be there when needed. It's just that, in your case, `B` is never called on, ever, during the execution of your program.

Comment: @Jeremy: Do I understand you correctly that class B will be loaded when A.methodWithB() is called? Or some othe code will run new B()? I mean the class loader will make an attempt to load B...

Comment: @Max: `B` will be loaded when you create a new instance in order to pass it into your method.

Comment: @Jeremy: Jeremy, one more question about constructor+classloading. How would system behave if in `module1.jar` we have call `A.methodWithB(null)`? Would it crash with null pointer inside A (B is used there), or would it report a missing class definition?

Answer (score 2):

If B is not *used* by A anywhere, then the resulting bytecode will have no reference to module2.B, therefore it gets compiled away. No dependency exists, *except* at compilation in this case.

If the question is unclear and B *is* used in A somewhere, then I'd be interested in seeing more code to try to determine what's going on.

Comment: The classes are already compiled, so nothing is "compiled away" here. The bytecode that references `B` still exists. Simply put, the runtime doesn't care about `B` until you need to use one.

Comment: Ah, you're right - the reference exists and isn't chased. I thought without it being used, that it would have just not bothered generating the reference to B in the bytecode in the first place. I should have checked via javap first.

Comment: I've edited my #4 point. You're right, `methodWithB(B param)` is never called. Actually, I miss some details on HOW it is possible object `A` is created?

Answer (score 1):

Look at it from the perspective of the classloader.  If you never have to load the class, you don't care if the bytecode for that class is missing.

Your question is really, "What triggers classloading?"

Two reasons I can think of off the top of my head are:
- Construction
- Static access